# Shortest path of length l in R

Tags: r, graph, igraph, shortest-path

I want to find shortest path of length l or smaller with least cost in a weighted graph consisting of vertices and edges.

```
  shortest_paths(g,from,to,output="both",weights=wts)
```

in R(from igraph package) gives shortest path between from and to vertices of least cost with no constraint on length l.

[image: See sample graph]

For example in this graph shortest path between 2 and 7 is 2 1 3 7 of length 3 but I want shortest path of length 2 i.e 2 1 7 of minimum cost.

Can someone guide me on how to proceed.

Comment: Could you provide an example dataset and from which package shortest_paths comme from.

Comment: I have edited the question to add an example to better clarify my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example,  there is only one path of length two from 2 to 7. That makes it difficult to test if we are really getting the minimum cost path. So,  I have added a link to create an extra path of length 2.

```
## Extended example
to     = c(1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,3,3,6)
from   = c(2,3,4,5,6,7,4,6,5,7,7)
weight = c(19,39,40,38,67,68,14,98,38,12,10)
EDF = data.frame(to, from, weight)
G   = graph_from_data_frame(EDF, directed = FALSE)
LO = layout_as_star(G, center=1, order = c(1,4,2,5,6,3,7))
plot(G, layout=LO, edge.label=E(G)$weight)
```

[image: Extended network]

The idea is to start with *all* paths from 2 to 7 and select only those that meet the constraint - length of path <= 2 (Note that means numbers of vertices <=3). For those paths, we compute the weight and select the one with the minimum cost.

```
maxlength = 2       ## maximum number of links
ASP = all_simple_paths(G, "2", "7")
ShortPaths = which(sapply(ASP, length) <= maxlength+1)
ASP[ShortPaths]
[[1]]
+ 3/7 vertices, named, from af35df8:
[1] 2 1 7
[[2]]
+ 3/7 vertices, named, from af35df8:
[1] 2 6 7
```

As you can see there are two paths with length two.  We need to find the one with minimum cost. To make this easy, we create a function to compute the weight of a path.

```
PathWeight = function(VP) {
    EP = rep(VP, each=2)[-1]
    EP = EP[-length(EP)]
    sum(E(G)$weight[get.edge.ids(G, EP)])
}
```

Now it is easy to get all of the path weights.

```
sapply(ASP[ShortPaths], PathWeight)
[1]  87 108
```

And to choose the smallest one

```
SP = which.min(sapply(ASP[ShortPaths], PathWeight))
ASP[ShortPaths[SP]]
[[1]]
+ 3/7 vertices, named, from af35df8:
[1] 2 1 7
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer :)

Comment: ASP = all_simple_paths(G, "2", "7")  function is computationally very expensive, takes lot of time as it enumerates all possible path and is not at all possible for large graphs. Is there a way to avoid this?